# Reverse engineering proprietary floating point number encoding

Tags: floating-point, decode, reverse-engineering, decoding, ieee-754

I'm trying to analyse some old binary format which don't have any specification. I figured out that there is an array of 96 floating point numbers, each 4-bytes long.

I've spent a lot of time with different hex<->float tools but without luck. I couldn't find any pattern. So I suspect it is some kind of unusual float representation, not some standard like IEEE-754.

Here is a long list of examples how bytes map to float value: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e67dd27706ba1f289a895fef70399dc9

Few examples:

```
80 00 00 80   =  0
00 FF 00 00   =  0
B8 EB 83 43   =  1.86281420496466
F8 AF 86 43   =  1.9018805660946
7B C2 F2 43   =  3.42793766176755
37 43 F5 43   =  3.46327992859723
6A 4D 03 44   =  3.70816455369089
26 C6 0A 44   =  3.919173581123
AF C3 79 43   =  1.76342447568475
```

I'm able to provide float value for any bytes combination that might be useful for analysis.

Could you please help me figure out the formula how to convert these raw bytes to float?

Comment: What are the float values for `00 00 00 43`, `01 00 00 43`, `02 00 00 43` and `00 00 00 44`?

Comment: Here are the values:

`00 00 00 43 = 0.903725041656076`

`01 00 00 43 = 0.903725149388496`

`02 00 00 43 = 0.903725257120917`

`00 00 00 44 = 3.6149001666243`

One more thing, all data are presented in the order from file, maybe they should be reversed for analysis.

Comment: @pliber What would likely help are examples of negative operands, along with very large and very small (in magnitude) ones, as well as examples across multiple *consecutive* binades (e.g. in [1,2), [2, 4), [4,8), [8,16), [16,32).

Comment: @pliber: Can you provide any context about where these values are coming from? I'm wondering whether there's some type of implicit unit conversion going on.

Comment: Mark Dickinson: These are fluorescence reads from instrument Roche LightCycler 480. I'm analysing experiment file and this array was encoded with Base64. What I do to get these float values is to modify raw bytes in project file, import it back to the LightCycler software and export again. So I don't have exact knowledge if there is some additional conversion going on inbetween.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By sorting the values, it is clear that the endianness has swapped (so 1.86281420496466 is really `43 83 EB B8`.

Plotting these hex values against the float values show that it is linear after the 9th bit, so bits 10-32 appear to be the significand with an implicit leading bit (`m`).

The first bit then seems to be the sign (1 for negative, 0 for positive).

Bits 2 through 9 appear to be a biased exponent (`e`)

The general form of the number is then:

sign × 2<sup>`e`-134</sup> × 0.903725041656076 × (1 + `m`/2<sup>23</sup>)

If the biased exponent is zero, then the value itself is zero.

I'm not sure why there is a funny constant there.

UPDATE: It does appear to match IEEE754 binary32, if multiplied by `141.636`, other than the handling of zero (ie. it flushes subnormal to zero).

In Julia, the conversions can be done as:

```
julia> reinterpret(UInt32,Float32(1.86281420496466*141.636)) # float to hex
0x4383ebb8

julia> reinterpret(Float32,0x4383ebb8)/141.636 # hex to float
1.862814204964663
```

Comment: What does not seem to make sense for a binary format is that 1.76.. and 3.46.. should share the same "exponent byte" value, namely `0x43`. I am wondering whether a higher radix than 2 might be used here.

Comment: njuffa: I'll try to generate more numbers from ranges you mentioned in your previous comment.

Thanks Simon, I have to think about this strange constant.   I've checked and first bit is indeed sign (1 negative, 0 positive)

Comment: Simon, 'x' should be 'e' in your equation? Am I right?

Comment: @pliber I think a look at the encoding of small integers would also help. So far I have consider floating-point formats, fixed-point formats, and logarithmic number systems, but nothing seems to fit exactly. The two examples of "0" seem to suggest that flush-to-zero may be used.

Comment: @Simon Byrne: So an implicit scale factor of sqrt(2)? Weird.

Comment: @SimonByrne: How to perform this IEEE754 conversion? Could you please explain it a little bit more? I will have a task to save standard float from my own program to this weird format.

Comment: I confirmed (using the examples from the GitHub linked in the question) that the scale factor appears to be exactly `141.636f`. So question is answered, answer upvoted. I did a quick internet search, but the significance of this conversion factor isn't clear, it doesn't seem to fit any pairs of widely used units.

Comment: OK, sorry, I got this now, I was calculating mantissa in silly way. This factor also seems to work. So I will just generate floats in my application and divide them by this factor before writing to file. Thanks everyone for help!